# Write Unit Test In Different Package Calling Private/Protected Methods Using Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I realize this question has been asked before here -> [How to create a test directory in Intellij 13?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28160379/how-to-create-a-test-directory-in-intellij-13)

However, the answer is not working for me and I can't figure out why...

**Intellij Version:**

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.4
Build #IC-145.2070, built on August 2, 2016
JRE: 1.8.0_77-b03 x86
JVM: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM by Oracle Corporation
```

***MyApp.java***

```
package main.java.com.simpleproject;

public class MyApp {
    private int updNum;

    public MyApp(int givenNum){
        this.updNum = givenNum;
    }

    private void updateNumPlusTwo(){
        this.updNum += 2;
    }

    protected int getUpdatedNum(){
        return this.updNum;
    }
}
```

***MyAppTest.java***

```
package test.java.com.simpleproject;

import main.java.com.simpleproject.MyApp;

public class MyAppTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyApp app = new MyApp(4);

        app.getUpdatedNum();
        app.updateNumPlusTwo();
    }
}
```

**The package/directory tree:**

[image]

**The Issue:**

[image]

**What I have tried:**

[image]

Anyone have any idea how to get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sources directories and packages are wrong.

1. You have chosen the Maven default sources directories structure of `src/main/java` for production code, and `src/test/java` for test code. You should declare both directories as source folders in IntelliJ (Project Structure -> Modules -> select the folders and click on Sources for `src/main/java` and Tests for `src/test/java`)
2. Your packages should be the same: `com.simpleproject`. The problem is that you have declared 2 different packages (`main.java.com.simpleproject` and `test.java.com.simpleproject`) that's why you cannot call a protected method.
3. It is not possible to call a private method, from the same or different package. You have to use reflection for that. But preferably you should at least put your method protected or package default.
4. Your test should use JUnit, not a main method. Something like :

   ```
   package com.simpleproject;

   import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat; 

   public class Test {   

       @Test
       public void shouldTestMyClass() {
          // Given
          int givenNum = 3;

          // When
          MyApp myApp = new MyApp(givenNum);
          myApp.updateNumPlusTwo();

          // Then (use AssertJ library for example)
          assertThat(myApp.getUpdatedNum()).isEqualTo(5);
       }

   }
   ```

Comment: Here are all the problems I see when trying this -> https://i.imgur.com/h50UtZE.png

Comment: What the problem looks like after changing `package main.java.com.simpleproject;` to `package com.simpleproject;` in "MyApp.java" -> https://i.imgur.com/o7das2w.png

Comment: I would also like to add the person got these different directories working using eclipse -> https://coderanch.com/i/3247074/eclipse-test-2.png

Comment: ok. Remove the 'private' modifier for the method updateNumPlusTwo. And you need to import JUnit : Project Structure -> Libraries

Comment: If you don't want to use JUnit, you can try with your main method, there is no need to import anything.

Comment: I'll keep this simple and try the main method for now. Until I can get this working as shown in the eclipse screen shot. Oh wow, it works (for protected) -> https://i.imgur.com/uWwJrE1.png. As for private... if I wanted to test private methods, do I have to write test methods in the same class (or is there a better practice for this)?

Comment: The best practice is to remove the private modifier, in order to make the method accessible from your test class. Google guys from Guava or Android projects use the @VisibleForTesting marker annotation : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33267820/how-to-use-visiblefortesting-for-pure-junit-tests/33279777

Comment: I see that private methods can still be called by protected methods (called by testClass in a different directly) as long as the private/protected methods are in the same class as shown -> https://i.imgur.com/5tVvidT.png. However, is understood in universal industry, when writing any private methods, these methods will not be tested directly?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. Private methods will be tested along with other protected, package default or public methods.